# Meteor.js Data storage SimpleSchema object type: [array]

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-autoform

I would like to add some article attachments and these attachments that were associated with the article

Hi I have created schema data in a form:

```
Docs = new SimpleSchema({
  fileName: {
    type: String,
    label: "Tytuł załącznika",
    optional: true
  },
  fileId: {
    type: String,
    label: "Nazwa pliku",
    autoform: {
      afFieldInput: {
        type: "cfs-file",
        placeholder: 'Prosze dodaj załącznika...',
        collection: "files"
      }
    },
    optional: true
  }
});

Schemas.Wydarzenie = new SimpleSchema({
  ...
    docs:{
      type: [Docs],
      label: "Załączniki",
    },
    ...
});
```

The package `aldeed:autoform` can save files in the array that is associated with the article by `_id`.
The data stored in the database schema for the `Schemas.Wydarzenie`:

```
{
  "_id" : "re4RyFScYEAmSEnGB",
  "docs" : [ { 
     "fileName" : "fsdfsdfsdfs f df fsf", 
     "fileId" : "mkEjjc5zjQW2Fdzuu" 
    }, { 
     "fileName" : "khjkhjkhkhjkhjj",
     "fileId" : "YvtbaFT3e7EwgZwrf" 
    } 
  ]
}
```

The data stored in the database schema for the "Docs":

```
{ 
  "_id" : "mkEjjc5zjQW2Fdzuu",
  "original" : { 
    "name" : "kazimierz.pdf", 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2015-10-13T11:46:37.370Z"),
    "size" : 64098, "type" : "application/pdf"
   },
  "uploadedAt" : ISODate("2016-02-09T06:46:08.910Z"),
  "copies" : { 
   "files" : { 
     "name" : "kazimierz.pdf",
     "type" : "application/pdf",
     "size" : 64098,
     "key" : "files-mkEjjc5zjQW2Fdzuu-kazimierz.pdf",
     "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-02-09T06:46:08Z"),
     "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-02-09T06:46:08Z") 
   } 
 } 
}


{
 "_id" : "YvtbaFT3e7EwgZwrf",
 "original" : {
   "name" : "porąbka.pdf",
   "updatedAt" : ISODate("2015-10-13T11:46:42.075Z"),
   "size" : 72654,
   "type" : "application/pdf"
 },
 "uploadedAt" : ISODate("2016-02-09T06:46:09.208Z"),
 "copies" : {
   "files" : {
    "name" : "porąbka.pdf",
    "type" : "application/pdf",
    "size" : 72654,
    "key" : "files-YvtbaFT3e7EwgZwrf-porąbka.pdf",
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-02-09T06:46:09Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-02-09T06:46:09Z")
   }
  }
 }
```

You are reset higher data schema can be used without installing a package `aldeed:autoform`.

If so can someone explain to me how to go about it.

Comment: can you please explain what you are trying to ask

Comment: I would like to add some article attachments and these attachments that were associated with the article